# Detecting daily recurrency in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Data Frame like this

```
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Team':pd.np.random.choice(['CHI', 'DAL'], 20),
               'Date':pd.date_range('2014-11-01', '2014-11-20')})
df.drop(14, inplace=True)
df
    Date    Team
0   2014-11-01  DAL
1   2014-11-02  CHI
2   2014-11-03  CHI
3   2014-11-04  DAL
4   2014-11-05  CHI
5   2014-11-06  CHI
6   2014-11-07  DAL
7   2014-11-08  DAL
8   2014-11-09  DAL
9   2014-11-10  DAL
10  2014-11-11  CHI
11  2014-11-12  CHI
12  2014-11-13  CHI
13  2014-11-14  CHI
# Notice there is no day here.
15  2014-11-16  CHI
16  2014-11-17  CHI
17  2014-11-18  CHI
18  2014-11-19  CHI
19  2014-11-20  DAL
```

I would like to find the number of days that a team played in a row.

Comment: If this question looks familiar, it's because it was posted before and deleted by the author. I had my answer written, but never got a chance to post it and since I wanted to share it, so I reposted the question, simplified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this to my knowlage is with iteration. This is not as optimal as with vectorized functions, but since you need to carry information between n rows, I do not see that vectorization is possible.

Therefore I came up with this algorithm:

```
n_days_in_row_played = 1
last_team = ""
last_date = datetime(1,1,1)
n_days = []
for row in df[(['Date', 'Team'])].iterrows():
    i, data = row
    date, team = data
    if team != last_team or (date - last_date).days > 1:
        last_team = team
        n_days_in_row_played = 1
    else:
        n_days_in_row_played += 1
    n_days.append(n_days_in_row_played)
    last_date = date
df['n_days'] = n_days
df
    Date    Team    n_days
0   2014-11-01  DAL     1
1   2014-11-02  CHI     1
2   2014-11-03  CHI     2
3   2014-11-04  DAL     1
4   2014-11-05  CHI     1
5   2014-11-06  CHI     2
6   2014-11-07  DAL     1
7   2014-11-08  DAL     2
8   2014-11-09  DAL     3
9   2014-11-10  DAL     4
10  2014-11-11  CHI     1
11  2014-11-12  CHI     2
12  2014-11-13  CHI     3
13  2014-11-14  CHI     4
# Skipped day resets the count.
15  2014-11-16  CHI     1
16  2014-11-17  CHI     2
17  2014-11-18  CHI     3
18  2014-11-19  CHI     4
19  2014-11-20  DAL     1
```

We keep in mind what the last team was and the last date played was

For each new line we compare if either the team changed or if there was more than one day passed, then the chain of days are broken, so we reset.

Otherwise we count plus one on the days in a row played

In the end we append the value of the days played to a list which we can attach to our original dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

The following should be more optimised, basically I'd `groupby` on the team, apply a boolean test of whether the difference in the datetime is equal to a timedelta of 1 day.

Then for where this is True then apply a `cumsum` on this and add 1.

Then fill the `NaN` values:

```
In [51]:
df['consec_days'] = df.sort('Date').groupby('Team')['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.diff() == dt.timedelta(1)) 
df.loc[df['consec_days'] == True,'n_days'] = df.loc[df['consec_days']==True].groupby('Team')['consec_days'].apply(pd.Series.cumsum) + 1
df['n_days'] = df['n_days'].fillna(1)
df

Out[51]:
            Date Team consec_days  n_days
index                                    
0     2014-11-01  DAL       False       1
1     2014-11-02  CHI       False       1
2     2014-11-03  DAL       False       1
3     2014-11-04  CHI       False       1
4     2014-11-05  DAL       False       1
5     2014-11-06  DAL        True       2
6     2014-11-07  DAL        True       3
7     2014-11-08  DAL        True       4
8     2014-11-09  CHI       False       1
9     2014-11-10  DAL       False       1
```

Comment: Your solution works on this exact dataset, but is not a general solution. I updated the questions example to show more of the problem.